# how to remove a IO::Async::Listener (or its notifier) object from a IO::Async::Loop event in perl

Tags: perl, asyncsocket, unix-socket, io-socket

I have a piece of code that creates a UNIX domain socket using IO::Socket::UNIX and gives it to an instance of IO::Async::Listener to handle listening on the socket and notifying on receiving data. The IO::Async::Listener, then, is added to a IO::Async::Loop event loop instance. 
The sockets are created dynamically in a controlled manager, of course.

On a certain condition, I'd like to remove the socket from the event loop (completely delete it, or temporarily disable it on other conditions if possible) but I don't know how.

IO::Async::Loop offers to remove IO::Async::Notifier objects from the event loop via $loop->remove( $notifier ) but creating the notifier was handled internally by IO::Async::Listener (via IO::Async::Stream, I presume?). Even on Ctrl-C of my script, the socket file is not deleted, do I just have to manually `close $socket and unlink( $path )` of the socket file?

Here's an abstract code of the desired behavior:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Async::Loop;
use IO::Async::Listener;
use IO::Socket::UNIX;

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;
my $listener = IO::Async::Listener->new(
                    on_stream => sub {
                            my ( undef, $stream ) = @_;

                            $stream->configure(
                                    on_read => sub {
                                            my ( $self, $buffref, $eof ) = @_;
                                            $self->write( $buffref );
                                            $buffref = "";
                                            return 0;
                                    },
                            );

                            $loop->add( $stream );
                    },
            );
$loop->add( $listener );

my $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
            Local => "echo.sock",
            Listen => 1,
            ) || die "Cannot make UNIX socket - $!\n";

$listener->listen(
            handle => $socket,
            );

my $condition = true;

while($condition) {
            // this is probably wrong
            $loop->remove( $listener );
            $condition = false;
}
```

Comment: `$socket and unlink( $path )` works but this doesn't remove the IO::Async::Listener object from the IO::Async::Loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two related questions here.

You can remove the listener object from the loop by using the loop's `remove` method:

```
$loop->remove( $listener )
```

However, removing the listener from the loop won't unlink the socket node from the fileystem. For that you will need the `unlink` code you suggested.

Personally, in such code as creates sockets like this, I make use of an `END` block:

```
my $path = "echo.sock";
my $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
            Local => $path,
            Listen => 1,
            ) || die "Cannot make UNIX socket - $!\n";
END { $socket and unlink $path }
$SIG{INT} = $SIG{TERM} = sub { exit 1 };
```

The `$SIG` line is required to ensure that `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` still run the `END` block, rather than just causing the `perl` process to immediately terminate.

Finally, you should note that you can use a neater form of the `listen` method, rather than explicitly creating the `UNIX` socket in your case, you can just

```
my $listener = ...
$loop->add( $listener );

$listener->listen(
  addr => {
    family   => "unix",
    socktype => "stream",
    path     => "echo.sock",
  },
);
```

Though again in this case you will still need the `END` block.